# Is a comma required here or would an "and" or "-" make more sense?

Tags: commas

I'm writing on a reward text for a Kickstarter crowdfunding campaign.
Is it correct to set a comma in the sentence below or would an *and* or *-* make more sense in that context?

> You'll get your name listed on our website, if you like along with a link to your Twitter profile.

Comment: You definitely need a comma after *if you like* and before *along with a link*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people resist them, but this seems to me a fine candidate for a parenthetical. You are offering a single reward that can vary slightly in nature based on the donor's preference. I think it's simple and clear to write:

> You'll get your name (and a link to your Twitter profile, if you'd like) listed on our website.

This could be made even clearer if you ditch the slightly awkward "you'll get your" construction:

> We'll list your name (and a link to your Twitter profile, if you'd like) on our website.

Comment: Good answer. And nice phraseology ('this seems to me a fine candidate for a parenthetical'). The original is at best clumsy; I'm not trying to decide how _acceptable_ the single-comma version is. (People who say that wrong punctuation isn't 'ungrammatical' can't dispute this terminology.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rearrange the sentence thus:

> If you like, you'll get your name listed on our website along with a link to your Twitter profile.

Comment: I would understand your version of that sentence differently than the one in the question.